# Using MS Word Templates to allow a user to fill out a report

Tags: c#, automation, ms-word

I'm trying to create create a simple word template on the fly which would just contain text and a few text input fields and then open a new word document based on that template for the user to fill out. I don't think this would be too difficult using Word automation and C#, but I've never worked with Word's COM interface before.

Any links to examples or fresh examples on how to create a simple template with some text and a text input field and then how to open a document based on that template in C# would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "Office Interop" is the keyword you are looking for.

You'll find a starting point here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384

Several drawbacks involved (for instance, installed Office on client machine required; not advisable to be run as a server process), but might do the job for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look at that link!

Answer (score 2):

I have done a fair amount of work with Word automation - though not really so much with tempates... My advice would be first of all to have a look at the documentation that ships with the product - which is a simple matter of editing a word macro, and pushing F1 in the code editor. I have found that to be a rich source of information...

The other piece of advice I would give you is to try recording a macro in Word that covers any task you want to do, and then inspecting the code that is generated. This has proven invaluable to me in getting stuff up and running quickly...

Hope this helps...

Martin.